# React Native - My memoized item is re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following component

```
const Card = memo((props) => { 
    ...
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return ... && 
        prevProps.onPressOptions === nextProps.onPressOptions;
});
```

which, as you can see, is memoized.

I am rendering it as an item on my CardList

```
const CardList = ({... , onPressCardOptions  , ...}) => {
   ...

   const renderItem = useCallback(({item, index}) => {
      return ( 
        <Card
          {...item} 
          onPressOptions={() => onPressCardOptions?.(item)} // <----
        />
      );
   }, [onPressCardOptions]);

   return (
      <FlatList
         renderItem={renderItem}
         keyExtractor...
      />
   );
}
```

The thing is, that because of the anonymous method defined in the renderItem method, my Card component memoization fails, it says that the next prop is different from the previous one.

How can I avoid this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have identified the problem, since it is an anonymous function it is different each time, but also since you are passing a parameter you cannot get rid of the anonymous function, or can you?

Yes, you can! you just need to change a little bit your code to make the Card component return the item instead

```js
const CardList = ({... , onPressCardOptions  , ...}) => {
   ...

   const renderItem = useCallback(({item, index}) => {
      return ( 
        <Card
          item={item} 
          onPressOptions={onPressCardOptions}
        />
      );
   }, [onPressCardOptions]);

   return (
      <FlatList
         renderItem={renderItem}
         keyExtractor...
      />
   );
}
```

```js
const Card = memo((props) => { 
    <View onPress={() => props.onPressOptions(props.item)}></View>
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return ... && 
        prevProps.onPressOptions === nextProps.onPressOptions;
});
```